# Does VisualStudio show the fully qualified assembly name of an open C# project somewhere?

Tags: c#

I have a C# project open in VisualStudio 2012. I see in the project properties page there is a field 'Assembly Name' but this appears to be only the filename of the resulting dll. I need to know / set the fully qualified assembly name ... I know how I can locate it at runtime by using C# code, but surely this is available within the IDE somewhere within an open C# project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs file, there are all the attributes you are searching for.

The "Fully Qualified assembly name" is a composition of all theses attributes.